# WIN32 Dialogue Box Throws exception

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

I am trying to learn the win32 api using the Microsoft documentation. I have gotten to chapter 4, and I seem to have run into an issue that I am struggling to debug. The dialogue box triggered by the about button throws an exception:

> Exception thrown at 0x773BDCFF (ntdll.dll) in practice.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00905A4C.

Here is the declaration of the WndProc and About callbacks:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
static INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

Here is the code for the implementation of the WndProc and About callbacks:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK App::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    App* pApp; 
    if (message == WM_CREATE) 
    {
        LPCREATESTRUCT pcs = (LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam;
        pApp = (App*)pcs->lpCreateParams; 
        ::SetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, PtrToUlong(pApp));
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        pApp = reinterpret_cast<App*>(static_cast<LONG_PTR>(::GetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA)));
        if (!pApp)
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam); 
    }

    int wmld, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT: 
            DialogBox(pApp->getInstance(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, pApp->About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK App::About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam); 
    switch (message) 
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG: 
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND: 
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
            {
                EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
                return (INT_PTR)TRUE; 
            } 
            break; 
    } 
        return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
```

I hope the error is within these snippets. If not, I would be happy to provide more code. I have done research, and I truly have very little idea what the problem is. I know that the callback for the about function must be static, which I believe it is. Apart from that, I don't know what would cause it to throw an exception. Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: Put a breakpoint here `DialogBox(pApp->getInstance()`, `pApp` is most likely a null or invalid pointer

Comment: Since `About` is static, you can even use `App::About` instead of `pApp->About` when calling `DialogBox` function. Even `pApp->getInstance()` can be replaced with `NULL` which defaults to current application.

Comment: "I hope the error is within these snippets". Run program under debugger. When exception is thrown, inspect call stack and if needed switch to last function which is yours. Check all pointers.

Comment: `PtrToUlong` can corrupt pointers in 64 bit mode.

Comment: Put the whole project somewhere, it'll be easier to check.

Comment: @DanielSęk That's a good point, but in this case the OP appears to be running a 32 bit build going by the addresses listed in the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fail to reproduce this issue using your presented code. The following is an example based on your code piece and it works for me. You can refer to.

App.h

```
class App
{
public:
    App(HINSTANCE hInstance, CONST WCHAR* clsName);
private:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    static INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance, CONST WCHAR* clsName);
};
```

App.cpp

```
#include "App.h"

App::App(HINSTANCE hInstance, CONST WCHAR* clsName)
{
    App::MyRegisterClass(hInstance, clsName);
}

ATOM App::MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance, CONST WCHAR* clsName)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = App::WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_DIALOGBOXEXCEPTION));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_DIALOGBOXEXCEPTION);
    wcex.lpszClassName = clsName;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK App::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    App* pApp;
    if (message == WM_CREATE)
    {
        LPCREATESTRUCT pcs = (LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam;
        pApp = (App*)pcs->lpCreateParams;
        ::SetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)pApp);
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        pApp = reinterpret_cast<App*>(static_cast<LONG_PTR>(::GetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA)));
        if (!pApp)
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, pApp->About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK App::About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Create the main window:

```
   App pApp = App(hInst, szWindowClass);
   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, &pApp);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);
```

Comment: @DanielSęk's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64962759/win32-dialogue-box-throws-exception?noredirect=1#comment114851642_64962759) applies here as well, `PtrToUlong(pApp)` will truncate the pointer and break the code in 64-bit compiles. The safe cast would be to `ULONG_PTR` instead.

Comment: @dxiv Right. Updated. Thanks.