# Read access violation using m_pRenderTarget with winapi due to non-NULL pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, winapi

I am following the Microsoft Docs for Windows api. I a currently on chapter 4 and trying to draw an ellipse. The `m_pRenderTarget` is declared in the class App.h. In the function `OnRender(HWND hwnd)` I am trying to use it to draw the geometry (ellipse). However, I am getting the following error:

> Exception thrown: read access violation. this->**m_pRenderTarget** was 0x38.

After some debugging, I noticed the in the `HRESULT App::CreateDeviceResources(HWND hwnd)` function, `m_pRenderTarget` was for some reason not NULL, even though I initialized it as such and hadn't yet changed it (I don't think at least). My guess is that this is the problem. For reference, here is the relevant code:

```
#pragma once
#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
#include "resource.h"
#include "pch.h"

class App
{
public:
    App();
    ~App();

    bool Init(HINSTANCE instance, int cmd);
    int RunMessageLoop();
    HINSTANCE getInstance() { return hInstance; }
private:
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];
    TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];

    ID2D1Factory* m_pD2DFactory; 
    ID2D1EllipseGeometry* m_pEllipseGeometry;
    ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* m_pRenderTarget;
    ID2D1SolidColorBrush* m_pBlackBrush;

    ATOM RegisterClass();
    BOOL InitInstance(int);
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    static INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    
    HRESULT CreateDeviceIndependentResources();
    HRESULT CreateDeviceResources(HWND hwnd);
    HRESULT OnRender(HWND hwnd);
};
```

Here are the implementations:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "App.h"


App::App()
    : m_pRenderTarget(NULL)
{}
App::~App(){}

bool App::Init(HINSTANCE instance, int cmd)
{
    hInstance = instance;
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_PRACTICE, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);

    RegisterClass();
    if (!InitInstance(cmd))
        return false;

    return true;
}

int App::RunMessageLoop()
{
    HACCEL hAccelTable;
    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_PRACTICE));

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}


//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM App::RegisterClass()
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_PRACTICE));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_PRACTICE);
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}


BOOL App::InitInstance(int nCmdShow)
{
    HRESULT hr = CreateDeviceIndependentResources();
    if FAILED(hr) 
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HWND hWnd;

    hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, this);


    if (!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//

LRESULT CALLBACK App::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    App* pApp; 
    if (message == WM_CREATE) 
    {
        LPCREATESTRUCT pcs = (LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam;
        pApp = (App*)pcs->lpCreateParams; 
        ::SetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, PtrToUlong(pApp));
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        pApp = reinterpret_cast<App*>(static_cast<LONG_PTR>(::GetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA)));
        if (!pApp)
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam); 
    }

    int wmld, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT: 
            DialogBox(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, pApp->About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        pApp->OnRender(hWnd);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK App::About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam); 
    switch (message) 
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG: 
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND: 
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
            {
                EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
                return (INT_PTR)TRUE; 
            } 
            break; 
    } 
        return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

HRESULT App::CreateDeviceIndependentResources() 
{
    HRESULT hr; 
    // Create a Direct2D factory 
    hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &m_pD2DFactory); 
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Create an ellipse geometry
        const D2D1_ELLIPSE ellipse = D2D1::Ellipse(D2D1::Point2F(105.0f, 105.0f), 25.0f, 25.0f); 
        hr = m_pD2DFactory->CreateEllipseGeometry(ellipse, &m_pEllipseGeometry); 
    }
    return hr;
}

HRESULT App::CreateDeviceResources(HWND hwnd) 
{
    //Notice that this causes HERE to be printed out, indicating that m_pRenderTarget != NULL
    if (m_pRenderTarget != NULL)
        OutputDebugStringA("\nHERE\n");
    else
        OutputDebugStringA("\nTHERE\n");

    HRESULT hr = S_OK; 
    if (!m_pRenderTarget) {
        
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc); 
        D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top); 
        // Create a Direct2D render target 
        hr = m_pD2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget( D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(), D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hwnd, size), &m_pRenderTarget ); 
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) 
        { // Create a black brush
            hr = m_pRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush( D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Black), &m_pBlackBrush ); 
        }
    }

    return hr; 
}

HRESULT App::OnRender(HWND hwnd) 
{ 
    HRESULT hr;

    hr = CreateDeviceResources(hwnd); 
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) 
    { 
        if (!(m_pRenderTarget->CheckWindowState() & D2D1_WINDOW_STATE_OCCLUDED)) 
        {

            m_pRenderTarget->BeginDraw(); 
            m_pRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White));
            m_pRenderTarget->FillGeometry(m_pEllipseGeometry, m_pBlackBrush); 
            hr = m_pRenderTarget->EndDraw(); 
            if (hr == D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET) 
            {
                hr = S_OK; 
                m_pRenderTarget->Release();
                m_pRenderTarget = NULL;
                m_pBlackBrush->Release(); 
                m_pBlackBrush = NULL; 
            }
        }
    }
    return hr;
}
```

I apologize for the amount of code I am offering. I am completely confused about the problem as I had thought that I was copying exactly what was written in the docs. I suppose I must have made an error in transcription. Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the value to see when it changes.

Comment: Where do you create the initial `App` instance?

Comment: `App::App() : m_pRenderTarget(NULL){}` -- You should initialize **all** of your members, not just that one.

Comment: *I am following the Microsoft Docs for Windows api* -- The Windows API is `C`-based, not C++.  You're not really following any documentation that shows how to create a C++ class that properly wraps the Windows API.  This is your invention -- so you need to show us a [mcve].

Comment: [Rules for Using Pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/rules-for-using-pointers): *"Use the `PtrToLong` or `PtrToUlong` function to **truncate pointers**. [...] After you convert a pointer variable using one of these functions, **never use it as a pointer again**."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you wrote an extra parameter when using the `CreateWindow` function, which caused `hInstance` to be acquired by `lpCreateParams`, which caused an access exception.

Just modify the code as follows:

```
hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), this);
```

And it works for me:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This kind of issue screams one of the following:

- your class pointer is invalid through being destroyed, uninitialized, or otherwise;
- you have stack or heap corruption *e.g.* buffer overflow or other undefined behavior.

Now, let's look at the strings appearing in your class, which are candidates for buffer overflow.  Nope, it looks like you're initializing those fine.

Okay, more static analysis.  Work backwards from where the issue happens.

- who called `CreateDeviceResources`?  It was `OnRender`
- who called `OnRender`?  It was the `WM_PAINT` handler.
- that call is very simple: `pApp->OnRender(hWnd);`
- so, is `pApp` valid?  Where is that initialized?
- it's stored in the window long pointer -- when is that stored?

And this leads me to this line:

```
::SetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, PtrToUlong(pApp));
```

Okay, what's fishy about that?  Well, `PtrToULong` is not a function (or macro) I've ever used, but based on its name, I'm immediately suspicious because I'm used to programming in 64-bits and I know that the type `ULONG` in Windows API is 32-bit.

So, I go and check the docs, and sure enough I find that's the case.  Not only this, but I find several writings about how this is actually a common culprit for breaking programs when porting to 64-bit.

Note that you could have arrived here already if you had attached your debugger, which would break when the access violation occurs.  And then you could have looked at the call stack.  You could then check the other contents of your `pApp` class and probably see the entire thing is corrupt.

At this point, you just go "hey I know this is sketchy", and you change the line to something like:

```
::SetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pApp));
```

Now you compile your program and try again.  I'm willing to bet that it works.  So much so, that I've written this entire answer based on that bet.

Another way you could have arrived at this particular path of investigation would have been to print out the value of `this` in your `App` constructor, and check it again in `OnRender` when you saw things go wonky.

Comment: I made the change you suggested, but it still threw the error:Exception thrown: read access violation.
this->m_pRenderTarget was 0x38.

Comment: Is your program being compiled as 32 bits or 64 bits?

Comment: Good bet, paddy. That caster-proc from basestd.h is definitely wrong in that spot, and replacing it with the LONG_PTR cast brought life.

Comment: My programs is compiled as 64 bits.

Comment: @johndoe The same `PtrToULong` fault was noted under the other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64962759/win32-dialogue-box-throws-exception/64965453#comment114851642_64962759).

Comment: Oh, no... I'm done with you then, mate.  Hopefully through my description you learned something about the type of thinking you can use to investigate.  If you made this change, you should see that your debug messages no longer report the value is non-NULL.  If they do, you have another issue (lifetime of your `App` object maybe, which you have not shown).  Otherwise, attach your debugger and look at the callstack where this exception happens.  Investigate from there.  `0x38` is a very suspicious value for a pointer.  Bye.